# Can i use blender 3d model for commercial purpose?

Tags: unity-game-engine, 3d, licensing, blender, 3d-modelling

I am new for blender. I designed a 3D car model in blender for my unity 3D project and plan to publish my game for commercial use. So I don't know the type of license blender uses.

**Do I need a license for blender to use the 3D modeling commercially?** Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about legal advice.

Answer (score 2):

**Yes, you can use Blender**. Blender's license does not place any restrictions on what you can do with the models you make with it:

> What you create with Blender is your sole property. All your artwork –
>   images or movie files – including the .blend files and other data
>   files Blender can write, is free for you to use as you like.
>
> That means that Blender can be used commercially by artists, by
>   studios to make animation films or vfx, by game artists to work on
>   commercial games, by scientists for research, and by students in
>   educational institutions.

Source: https://www.blender.org/about/license/

Comment: Thank for reply. Did you mean i can use my blender 3d model commercially without any license?